# I have a doubt regarding FFT size in 5G NR 60 MHz Bandwidth

Tags: fft, matlab, digital-communications, dsp-core, digital

maximum RBs for 60MHz with SCS = 30 kHz is defined to be 162 RBs, so NSubcarriers is 162 x 12 = 1944, 1944 < 2048. Then NFFT size for 60 MHz bandwidth with SCS = 30 kHz should be 2048 instead of 4096.

Comment: Where do you find that 3GPP specifies an FFT size 4096 for 30kHz subcarrier spacing 60MHz bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the below link -
https://in.mathworks.com/help/5g/ug/use-default-ofdm-sample-rate-and-default-fft-size.html
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error vector magnitude (EVM) windows are defined in Appendix B in 3GPP TS 38.104 in Tables B.5.2-1, B.5.2-2, and B.5.2-3. Same tables give also the FFT sizes. Obviously, you do not necessarily need to use those FFT sizes for OFDM waveform generation but the EVM windows are defined for those sizes.